# Is there an SQL function to select sample from a database based on calculation of converted substrings of a specific column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, type-conversion, data-cleaning

I have a large table that I'm trying to filter down however the data I have is quite dirty.

I need to find contracts with less than a certain amount of time left however there is only one column that contains the contracts' timings. Let's call this column **"Term"**. The data within **Term** looks roughly as follows:

```
*x* years from *dd mmmm yyyy*
```

For example, for a contract of 30 years starting on 12/12/2020 that row's entry in the column **Term** would look like:

```
30 years from 12 December 2020
```

The task is to find contracts with less than *x* amount of years remaining. As you may tell by the language I'm using in this question, I'm a bit of a noob so go easy on me. I've tried the following *(for this example let's assume I'm looking for contracts with less than 10 years remaining however some of these contracts can be over 100 years)*:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb WHERE
(CAST(LEFT(`Term`,POSITION(" " IN `Term`)) AS DECIMAL(4,0))) + (CAST(RIGHT(`Term`,4) AS DECIMAL(4,0))) - year(curdate()) < 10
```

But obviously it's not working and I don't know why

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server? You use backticks (`\``) to delimit identify your objects in your SQL; that isn't a valid delimit identifier in T-SQL.

Comment: Nor does tsql have POSITION and CURDATE functions. Seems like you are using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This works in MySql 8 and MariaDB 10

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    , CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Term, '([0-9]+)(?= year[s]?)') AS UNSIGNED) as term_years
    , STR_TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Term, '[0-9]{1,2} [A-Za-z]{3,} [0-9]{4}'), '%d %M %Y') as term_start_date
    FROM mydb
) q
WHERE (YEAR(term_start_date) + term_years) < (YEAR(CurDate()) + 10)
```

| id | Term | term_years | term_start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 9 year from 16 April 2021 | 9 | 2021-04-16 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=0e976f1b867fedac9e71186965179e97)*